# Inserting generated image into an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, excel-2007

How can I insert an in-memory bitmap generated in c# into an Excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, One of the easiest ways is to use the clipboard and the office sdk.  Simply put your image bits on the clipboard, and then paste them into the sheet.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10502/here-is-the-solution.aspx